# Route 53 DNS Failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, failover

I want to test out Route 53 DNS Failover. My scenario:

I have a Primary webserver that runs a web portal located in our Primary DC
This webserver is a virtual machine running on Hyper-V and we have setup Replication so it replicates to a server in another Data Centre (Secondary DC)
The web portal has a DNS CNAME entry on Route53 example failover.mycompany.com that points to an A record for the Public IP to that server
Our firewall is setup with Virtual IPs to allow the site to access the webserver

I have created an A record for the secondary site and setup virtual IP so if primary is down I can failover the VM to the secondary site and be able to access it. I have tested and I am able to access from the other DC by updating the route on the CNAME to the other site.

I want to test out failover and have been reading and looking at YouTube videos. I created a healthcheck and can set the CNAME to failover instead of simple routing. But I have to create another record.

Is it possible to create another CNAME record and set the failover option on and route to the secondary DC? Can you create a CNAME with the same name? so have 1 CNAME record as failover.mycompany.com pointing to Primary DC then create another CNAME with same name but point it to secondary DC?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here but for "Can you create a CNAME with the same name?"  the answer is no. If you have a `CNAME` record you can not have anything else, for obvious reasons. If you have `x CNAME a` and `x CNAME b` and `a` pointing to one IP and `b` to another, which one is the correct one? To avoid such problems, a `CNAME` is exclusive of everything else. Also the DNS operates in load balancing by default, not in fail over.

Comment: I am trying to test the failover functionality of Route53. So I read you have to create a health record for the primary and I created one for the DNS name failover.mycompany.com. I can set on the CNAME the routing protocol to Failover and select the health record. I'm a little confused on how to setup the secondary point so if Primary fails it goes to secondary. Right now if Primary fails, I have to edit the CNAME and change the route to a different A Record that points to a public IP. I am trying to limit having to manually do this so it does it automatically

Comment: As mentioned, it is not possible to have two CNAMEs with the same name. However, it does not look like your question is off topic. I don't know anything about failovers in Route 53 and would be curious to see the answer to your question.